# Writing Custom Extensions in Druid

Tags: druid

I am new to Druid.

**Problem Statement**
We do currently push raw event data to Druid. I have a requirement to apply certain calculations on the data (say like certain stat techniques) which are not supported by Druid or the extensions it provides out of the box.

There are two questions I have -

1. What would be a better way to achieve this? (Have some external script that reads data from Druid, computes the calculations and puts it back to Druid)?
2. Can I take a route of writing Custom Extensions on Druid? I could not find any good documentation on how do we go about writing/ testing Druid Extensions.

These link does not provide any in-depth information - 
http://druid.io/docs/latest/development/modules.html

https://github.com/apache/incubator-druid (Druid repo that has some core and community contrib extensions)

Appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this both ways now it's up to you how much comfortable you are writing an extension by yourself and then maintain it. This is certainly time-consuming compared to another way.

1. If you read data from druid and then perform your calculation and write data back to the druid, you will end up writing to the separate table. If you are not storge bound on druid cluster then you can certainly take this path and its less time-consuming.
2. Yes, this is the recommended way to perform any custom computation on data. You can certainly write a simple extension easily. Here's the example git hub repo link which helps to write a custom druid extension: https://github.com/implydata/druid-example-extension